# CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Using this code within an aspx file

```
<% if(storeid=1) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-abcd.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
<% else if(storeid=2) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-efgh.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
<% else if(storeid=3) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-ijklmn.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
<% else if(storeid=4) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-opqrs.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
```

Compiling this gives me this error

Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'

Source Error:

```
Line 62:    
Line 63:    // Specific Code test 17.4.2014
Line 64: <% if(storeid=1) { %>
Line 65:    <script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-abcd.js" async defer>   </script>
Line 66: <% } %>
```

All of the <% and %> look ok. Where is it falling down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `storeid == 1`, not `storeid=1`.

Comment: ... and all the other if-statements. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: Indeed, I have just saw at the code on the bottom :-)

Comment: thanks. Still getting the same error but gives me something to work on

Answer (score 4):

Replace this line:

```
<% if(storeid=1) { %>
```

With:

```
<% if( storeid == 1 ) { %>
```

By the way, this is true for all of the rest equality checks in the other lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

Your storeid='1' is wrong and the rest of your else statement. it should be `==`.

`storeid == 1` and not `storeid=1`.

```
<% if(storeid=1) { %>
```

should be

```
<% if(storeid==1) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-abcd.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
<% else if(storeid==2) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-efgh.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
<% else if(storeid==3) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-ijklmn.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
<% else if(storeid==4) { %>
<script src="//d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-1234-opqrs.js" async defer></script>
<% } %>
```